# Wifi turns off automatically in Ubuntu 16.04 if speed goes above 150 Mbps

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, iwlwifi

I have 5G internet connection. Speed is always between 200 - 300 Mbps. When I am downloading something and download speed goes above 150 Mbps, WiFi turn off. It doesn't even show available WiFis. Rebooting the system doesn't help. I have to shut down the system and start again. I researched and tried below solutions but unfortunately none worked.

1. Restart network manager.
2. Disable power management
3. Disable 11n
4. Uninstalled network-manager and installed WICD network manager
5. Reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04

My system:
Lenovo Thinkpad P52.
Wireless Card: Intel Wireless AC 9560

Anybody faced same issue and have solution? I will really appreciate the help as I am trying to resolve this issue for last 1 month and it's driving me crazy.

Thanks

---

Update:

I changed the setting of IPv6 from Automatic to Ignore. It's been 24 hours now, WiFi has not turned off. I hope this is the solution.

Update: Wifi turned off after 10 hours. So, this is not the fix.

---

[Solved]

Updated the kernel to 5.1.3 using Ukuu Kernel Update Utility. It's been 2 days now since laptop is up and running and WiFi is not turned off. Noticed other things as well after updating the kernel. WiFi Signal is always 100% now. Earlier it was always between 80 - 90 percent. Also, boot time has reduced significantly.

Comment: ` sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` will show interesting logs.

Comment: I see this twice,  it is in red colour - "nm_device_get_device_type: assertion 'NM_IS_DEVICE (self)' failed". But logs are only for last 36 hours. Wifi turned off before that. I will try to download something and once it gets disconnected, I will run the command again.

Comment: @waltinator Managed to reproduce the issue after reinstalling again. Here is the log - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PXxnVkz8fC/. If you look at the last 2 lines, it seems disconnect happened after 2 hours. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: @chili555 Will you be able to please help me with this?

Comment: See what else your system is doing around that time: `sudo journalctl --since="20-03-03 10:29:52" --until="20-03-03 05:28:52"` (that's 10 minutes before the disconnect)

Comment: @waltinator I upgraded the kernel. Issue is resolved and I have updated the question with the solution at the end.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]

Updated the kernel to 5.1.3 using Ukuu Kernel Update Utility. It's been 2 days now since laptop is up and running and WiFi is not turned off. Noticed other things as well after updating the kernel. WiFi Signal is always 100% now. Earlier it was always between 80 - 90 percent. Also, boot time has reduced significantly.